# build unity game to android

Tags: unity-game-engine, build

I tried to change the game to Android and got three errors

> CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed. C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.23f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\OpenJDK\Windows\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2017.4.23f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-5.1.1.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx4096m" "assembleRelease"

error 2

> Build completed with a result of 'Failed' UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

error 3

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 2 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (BuildPlayerOptions options) [0x00242] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:194 at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow.CallBuildMethods (Boolean askForBuildLocation, BuildOptions defaultBuildOptions) [0x0007f] in C:\buildslave\unity\build\Editor\Mono\BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:97 UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr) (at C:/buildslave/unity/build/Modules/IMGUI/GUIUtility.cs:179)

Comment: Currently your questions lacks a lot of information, meaning we can't do a lot for you. Please take a look at the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to improve your question

Answer (score 0):

Just from a glance, the errors above do not seem to be from your project, but trying to build a nearly-empty project will eliminate many possibilities.

My suggestion is to start with a new, empty Unity project and see if that project successfully can deploy to Android. Once you have that working, add one Package dependency at a time (if you have any) using the Package Manager, and make sure that works. If that all works, can try to build your existing project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the SDK installed, make sure your android device has drivers installed on your PC.